# Setting env variable as string arrays in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to read Queue names from docker-compose.override file. For that purpose, I have made them string arrays
and defined them like this below

`environment:`

```
 - RabbitMQOptions__ConnectionString=-rabbitmq
 - RabbitMQOptions__BrokerName=event_demo
 - RabbitMQOptions__QueueName=["sampleQueue", "daemonQueue"]
```

Docker compose file builds up just fine. But I am unable to get any of the values from the array.Is there any other way around to set up this env variable.

I am injecting the value from docker-compose file through Startup.cs file

```
services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, RabbitMQEventBus>(sp =>
        {
            var rabbitMQPersistentConnection = sp.GetRequiredService<IRabbitMQPersistentConnection>();
            var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMQEventBus>>();
            var eventBusSubcriptionsManager = sp.GetRequiredService<IEventBusSubscriptionManager>();
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<RabbitMQOptions>>();

            return new RabbitMQEventBus(options.CurrentValue, eventBusSubcriptionsManager, rabbitMQPersistentConnection, logger, services);
        });
```

And right here in constructor I obtain the value through dependency injection

```
 public RabbitMQEventBus(
        RabbitMQOptions options,
        IEventBusSubscriptionManager subscriptionManager,
        IRabbitMQPersistentConnection persistentConnection,
        ILogger<RabbitMQEventBus> logger,
        IServiceCollection services
        )
    {
        _persistentConnection = persistentConnection;
        _subsManager = subscriptionManager;
        _options = options;
        _queueName = _options.QueueName[0];
        _consumerChannel = CreateConsumerChannel();
        _subsManager.OnEventRemoved += SubsManager_OnEventRemoved;
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
        BROKER_NAME = _options.BrokerName;
    }
```

Here is RabbitMQOptions class

```
public class RabbitMQOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public string BrokerName { get; set; }

    public string[] QueueName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Environment variables are always simple strings, not arrays or other types.  Do you also control the code that's using this value, and if so, can you include it in the question?